# Make a chapter with its title in a box

Tags: chapters, boxes

I would like to frame the text below exactly as the screenshot shows:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could post what you've tried, so we don't have the hassle of typing everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Rejne` chapter titles from [`fncychap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fncychap). However, in order to use `\tableofcontents`, some modifications are required:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname}%
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\LaTeX{} Mathématique}

\section{Introduction au nombre de Stirling}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: thats work perfectly im very grateful thanks

Answer (score 5):

I hope that this MWE is OK!

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\chapter{\LaTeX~~I have put $\sim$ now thanks.}

bla bla blaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

\end {document}
```

Comment: it doesn't work when i add table of contents

Comment: Add `\tableofcontents` and `\newpage`after `\begin{document}` and after compiling the `.tex` file two times, you will get the following table of contents. Can you add your work?

Comment: BTW, \LaTeX (or any macro) eats the next space.  \LaTeX{} or \LaTeX\space or \LaTeX~ will put it back.

Comment: same problem it doesn't work

Comment: same problem it doesn't work error message appears when i add \tableofcontents